# C++: Finding the last occurence of a char in a string

Tags: c++

I've been working on this for nearly a couple hours. I believe my solution to be logically correct, however I don't get the desired output. For example, suppose I want to find the last time the character "h" appears in this string: "hlhhhlh" (6 if we start from 0).

My program compiles, but it doesn't work. This code only finds out when the first occurence of "h" from a char element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int getIndex(vector<char> arr, char t);

int main()
{
 vector<char> myArr(0);

 myArr.push_back('l');
 myArr.push_back('l');
 myArr.push_back('l');
 myArr.push_back('hlhh');
 int i = getIndex(myArr, 'h');
 cout << i << endl;
}

int getIndex(vector<char> myArr, char t)
{

int n=0, m=0, count=0;
string y,s;
vector<string> arr(0);

for(int i =0; i < myArr.size(); i++)
{
  stringstream st;
  st << myArr[i];
  st >> y;
  arr.push_back(y);
}

stringstream ss;
ss << t;
ss >> s;

for(int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++)
 {
    if(arr[i] == "h")
    {
        n++;
    }
    else if(arr[i] == "l")
    {
        m++;
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i< arr.size(); i++)
  {
      if(arr[i]==s)
      {
          count++;
          if(count == n)
          {
              return i;
          }
          else if(count == m)
          {
              return i;
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: "Nearly a couple of hours"? What does that mean? Not quite a couple, so just, like, 50 minutes?

Comment: use `std::string` and call `find_last_of()` will be better?

Comment: why don't you debug your program? It's really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'hlhh'` is not a c++ string and the char vector can only `push_back` single char with:

```
 myArr.push_back('l');
 myArr.push_back('l');
 myArr.push_back('l');
 myArr.push_back('h');
 myArr.push_back('l');
 myArr.push_back('h');
 myArr.push_back('h');
```

And as a better practice, the `getIndex` function should be:

```
int getIndex(vector<char> &myArr, char t);
```

instead of

```
int getIndex(vector<char> myArr, char t);
```

because `passing by value` will generate new `vector<char>` object and copy all the elements of the input object, thus producing performance overhead.

Answer (score 8):

You want `std::string::rfind`:

```
std::string s = "hlhhhlh";

std::cout << "The last 'h' in '" << s << "' is at position "
          << s.rfind('h') << std::endl; // output here is: The last 'h' in hlhhhlh is at position 6
```

(If the character doesn't occur in the string, `s.npos` is returned.)

Answer (score 1):

You're adding this: 'hlhh' a multibyte character

```
myArr.push_back('hlhh');
```

They need to be added individually i.e.

```
myArr.push_back('h');
myArr.push_back('l');
myArr.push_back('h');
myArr.push_back('h');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String with rfind() to find the last occurrence of the character in a string as suggested by "Kerrek SB".
If you want to use string with Vector then following example code will help you,

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<vector>
  #include<string>
  using namespace std;


  int main()
  {
     vector<string> arr(0);
     arr.push_back(string("h"));
     arr.push_back(string("l"));
     arr.push_back(string("h"));
     arr.push_back(string("l"));
     arr.push_back(string("h"));
     arr.push_back(string("h"));
     arr.push_back(string("l"));
     arr.push_back(string("h"));
     arr.push_back(string("l"));
     arr.push_back(string("h"));
     arr.push_back(string("l"));
     for (int i=arr.size()-1; i >=0; i--)
       if (arr[i] == string("h")) {
          cout<<"\n H is present at"<< i;
          break;
       }
    return 0;
   }
```